# Angular $compile is slow, how to avoid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nug671xm/1/

It is a simple tree layout. First click on a plus creates children, subsequent clicks expand and collapse the subtree. For large numbers of children the creation takes much longer than the other actions. I think the $compile calls are consuming most of the time.

What's the reason and is there a way to speed things up?

Code for the directive:

```
myApp.directive('myTree', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var template =
                '<ul><li ng-repeat="node in node.children">' +
                '<span ng-click="displayTree.selectNodeHead(node)">+ </span>' +
                '<span>{{node.name}}</span>' +
                '<div ng-hide="node.collapsed" my-tree></div></li></ul>';
            element.html('').append($compile(template)(scope));
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ng-repeat` and `$compile()` are notoriously slow for large iterations.  Use native JavaScript for iterations and adding your HTML string, and then use native `onclick` commands in place of `ng-click`.  This approach requires some major re-thinking and code refactoring, but the performance benefits are huge (I had converted a 500-item ng-repeat to native DOM, and render time went from 1.2s to .06s (95% improvement).

Here's an example of native JS and Angular working harmoniously on 1,000 items.  Rendering and responses are almost instant.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGygBK

Comment: I don't know about 'harmoniously'. There is no angular inside the iteration - so you basically throw away all the code structure benefits of using angular. Don't get me wrong - that may be called for in certain situations. :)

Comment: that's native? That's jQuery